# Is there a way to flush cached ip addresses in content in Liferay Portal

Tags: tomcat, liferay, admin, portal

I have a development instance and a test instance. I am using MSSQL , when i restore the database from development into test, the edit actions in the Portal front end have the development ip address in the content edit links. This means it redirects me to the dev instance when i go to add or edit content.

Is there somewhere I might change or flush this?

I am running on tomcat and windows

In my portal-ext.properties i have already:

```
redirect.url.security.mode=ip
```

and

```
redirect.url.ips.allowed=(my dev ip address),127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you generate those URLs that contain IP-Addresses? Could it be that they are contained e.g. in web content articles?

Also, check your settings, either in portal-ext.properties or in the database (e.g. through Control Panel/Server Administration. For example there's this setting that can be done in portal-ext.properties - maybe overridden in database:

```
#
# Set the hostname that will be used when the portlet generates URLs.
# Leaving this blank will mean the host is derived from the servlet
# container.
#
web.server.host=
```

If this doesn't solve it, you might have set a virtual host for the site in question or for the whole portal.

A quick way to backtrace might be to grep for the host name / ip address in a database dump and try to identify the relevance&origin of the hit(s)

Comment: Thanks Olaf, fantastic, yes you were right with the virtual host for the whole portal , I have changed the virtual host entry in the Portal Instances Administration.